# c# returning from sub form to main form at same location

Tags: c#

I have a main form , from where another form is opened to verify password, I want to return to same point from where this form was opened so that I can proceed accorddingly to the password verification, please see the code:-

```
        this.TopMost = false;

        FormPassword fPass = new FormPassword();

        fPass.Show();


        //I need it should wait here , but dosent,

        // i tried adding here 

        // while(fPass.Visible); //but didn't helped



        if (Variables.IsPasswordCorrect == true)//IsPasswordCorrect defined in variables.cs, to make it common in both the forms
        {

            DialogResult result2 = MessageBox.Show("Start the Process?", "START?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);

            if (result2 == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                StartAll();

            }



        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use ShowDialog like you are doing with result2, your code will wait for the dialog to complete before continuing:

```
  this.TopMost = false;

  FormPassword fPass = new FormPassword();

  fPass.ShowDialog();
```